# Lucene Index and search issue

Tags: indexing, lucene

I have an issue with a course session start date and end date while indexing in lucene. A course can have multiple sessions, and each session can have a start and end date. Say startdate1-enddate1, startdate2-enddate2....

Currently, I am indexing courseid and session start dates and end dates separately as multi value fields in lucene.  Something like course:[courseid1] startdate: [startdate1 startdate2...], enddate: [enddate1 enddate2 ...]

Now, my requirement is to find all courses which have a session starting or ending in the time range I pass AND the startdate and end dates should not be null.  Also, the startdate and end dates can be null and I save null date as 0.

Sessions->

> session1: 20151205  start date  null end date
>   session2: null start date 20151202 end date

In lucene indexing->

> sessionstartdate: 0 20151205, sessionenddate: 20151202 0

My lucene query->

```
sessionstartdate:[20151201 TO 20151210] sessionenddate:[20151201 TO 20151210]
```

Issue-> This query is finding the course, although it should not since both sessions have one null date.

So I modified the query to-

```
(sessionstartdate:[20151201 TO 20151210] - sessionenddate:0) (sessionenddate:[20151201 TO 20151210] -sessionstartdate:0)
```

This does not return course, which is fine but it now fails in the following scenerio-

> session1: 20151205  start date  null end date
>   session2: null start date 20151202 end date
>   session3: 20151201 start date 20151202 end date

I do not get any data back, even though I should.

Answer (score 0):

First:  Each clause in your query is, by default, treated as a `SHOULD` clause.  This means only 1 or more of these clauses must appear in any match (with higher score given to matches on both).  In order to *require* a query term to occur in any matches, it should be preceded with a `+`, so your query should be:

```
+sessionstartdate:[20151201 TO 20151210] +sessionenddate:[20151201 TO 20151210]
```

The problem now, is that you give yourself no way to match up session1's start and end date.  A query as above will match any pair of start and end dates.  So, you will still match the document with just session1 and session2, listed in your question, with this query, and as you've stated, that isn't what you want.

The best way to handle this would probably be to store sessions as entirely separate documents, and use Lucene's [Join API](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/package-summary.html) to handle the relation (By the way, the first question I'd ask myself when thinking about using joins in Lucene is *"Should I just use a relational database, instead?"*).